# Is constructor inherited in JS ECMAScript 6?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I have example class:

```
class Something{
    constructor(x, y){
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
    }

    //...
}
```

And when I'll make inherited class like this:

```
class Dog extends Something{
    constructor(name){
       this.name = name;
    }

    //...
}
```

Will Dog's constructor look like this?

```
constructor(x, y, name){
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.name = name;
}
```

If not, is it possible to make it working like this ^?

Comment: You need to create it explicitly using `super` in Dog's constructor like `super(x, y);`

Comment: Did you try this code? It will throw an exception because you left out `super`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is constructor inherited in JS ECMAScript 6?

Not really, no. But if you don't provide a constructor at all, the JavaScript engine provides a default that acts a bit like an inherited constructor.<sup>1</sup> (Not relevant to your example, you've provided a constructor in `Dog`.)

> Will Dog's class look like this?

No. Because you've defined the constructor in `Dog`, the JavaScript engine doesn't do anything for you; it's up to you to define `Dog`'s constructor and have it call `Something`'s via `super` (and you can't use `this` until you call `super`).

Your `Dog` constructor would need to either accept `x` and `y`, or hardcode its own (or derive them from the argument it does get):

Accepting them:

```
class Dog extends Something{
    constructor(name, x, y) {
       super(x, y);
       this.name = name;
    }

    //...
}
```

Hardcoding:

```
// Accepting them:
class Dog extends Something{
    constructor(name) {
       super(42, 57);
       this.name = name;
    }

    //...
}
```

(Or of course, accept only `x` or `y` and hardcode/derive the other one.)

---

<sup>1</sup> If you don't supply `constructor` at all, the JavaScript engine [adds one for you](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation).

For base classes, it looks like this:

```
constructor() {
}
```

For derived classes, it looks like this:

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
}
```

That latter one is why I say it's a bit like having an inherited constructor, because unlike languages like Java or C# where the default constructor accepts no arguments and calls `super` with no arguments, JavaScript's default passes through all arguments it receives.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, now I understand it. I'll accept your answer as helpful when I'll be able to do it (~10 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

You should call the base class constructor explicitly using

```
super(x, y);
```

in order to get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It does, ECMAScript 2015:

```
class Animal {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Hello");
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {}

var d = new Dog(); // Prints "Hello"
```